# jQuery Validation PlugIn : Callback for field success validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Im am using errorPlacement to add a class to a label to show a graphic element in addition to the error text ( they are both different elements).

Is there a way to use a callback that will fire when the validation of a field is successful? I am already using validClass, that will change the error message, but I need a call back so I can change the graphic element to a "success" one.

For Example

[graphic] [input field] [error text]

I was able to change the [graphic] and the [error text] when there is an error, but when the correct value is entered in the field I was able to change the [error text] but not the [graphic].

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the `success` option.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

```
$("#myform").validate({
   success: function(label) {
     label.addClass("valid").text("Ok!")
   },
   submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
})
```

If you pass a function to `success`, you are given back the label as a jQuery object. You can then manipulate that object or a related object.

---

Alternatively, your error and success graphic can use a background image, and then you can swap out the background image with CSS on the `validClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the defaults validClass: "valid" with validClass:"success"