# how to clear error when using jquery validate and custom errorPlacement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery and validate to validate my form.
Instead of adding an element to the missing field I am adding a border to the element
using this option errorPlacement

```
$("#signup-form").validate({
       submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      element.css("border", "solid 1px red");
   }                    
});
```

the one thing i can not seem to figure out is how to clear it when valid?

So I started with the above code. Then tried and i am confused with the results.
If I do not have the `success:` option when a field fails it adds the class successfully. But as soon as I add the `success` option all the required fields are getting that class, and if I inspect the element I see `<input class="required invalid valid">` so I am doing something incorrectly.

```
           $("#signup-form").validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    // do other stuff for a valid form
                    //form.submit();
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    element.addClass("invalid");
                },        
                success: function(error) {
                    // change CSS on your element(s) back to normal
                },                    
                 debug:true
            });
```

Comment: Normally, by default, the error clears itself.  Please explain more and/or show a demo of your problem.

Comment: i am adding the code above. so when a field fails instead if adding aa new element i am just changing the border of the missing field to red. if i put in the info and leave the field it still has the border.

Comment: You can refer to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518895/jquery-validation-plugin-callback-for-field-success-validation The success option has a callback which you can use to disable the label's border.

Comment: It solves my problems. But I cannot say why :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try adding this to your list of `.validate()` options...

```
success: function(error) {
    // change CSS on your element(s) back to normal
}
```

This should work dynamically without a form submit.  As soon as the error is resolved, the contained code will run.

See [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate).

Please create a demo of your problem using jsFiddle.  Here's [a blank jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLE2s/) with `.validate()` already included and ready for use.

---

**EDIT**

As per [OP's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paries/u3Td3/1/), I made these changes...

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').addClass("invalid");
    },
    success: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        $("#signup-form").find('.valid').removeClass("invalid");
    }
```

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/u3Td3/6/

**Side-notes:**  You also had some HTML issues.  You should "self-close" your `input` elements with `/>`.  Same thing for the submit button, self-close rather than using a `</input>`.  See [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML.  I'd also not use a `table` for layouts, use CSS.

Comment: @randy, since I can't see your HTML or your page, I can't write an exact solution.  Use jsFiddle to create a demo of your problem.  Here's [a blank jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLE2s/) with `.validate()` already included and ready for use.

Comment: thanks you example works except when the text fields are pre-filled.
getting closer
http://jsfiddle.net/paries/u3Td3/8/

Comment: I don't think that's anything to do with `success`, custom error placement, or your original question.  The new question is _'why is the `invalid` class being applied to non-empty fields on submit?'_

Comment: I'm glad I could help with this part at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="signupForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact">Your Name <em>(required)</em></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
</form>

$('#serviceForm').validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        element.parent().addClass("hasError");
    },
    success: function (error, element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass("hasError");
    }
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).