# Calling mail.php from form javascript and action form correctly

Tags: javascript, php, forms

PHP an JS novice here again.

I was using a ajax JS to action a script, but could not get the inline error message to work, so I scrapped that idea and went with HTML5 validation.

I statrted with the JS:

```
<script>

(function() {
    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            //return $('#mailForm').validate().form();
            $("#mailForm").validate({
                 rules: {
                    name: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 2
                    },
                    name2: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 2
                    },
                    "ic-passport": {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 6
                    },
                    phone: { 
                      required : true,
                      number:true,  
                      minlength : 10,
                      maxlength : 13
                    },
                    city: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 4
                    },
                    email:{ 
                       required: true,
                       email: true
                    },
                    dob: {
                       required: true,
                       date: true
                       minlength : 4
                    },
                    sex: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    tpt: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    licence: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    travel: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    language: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    ethnicity: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    religion: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    age: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    "hair-colour": {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    "hair-length": {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    "eye-colour": {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    height: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    weight: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    image1: "required",
                    bio: "required",
                    experience: "required",
                    femail:{ 
                       required: true,
                       email: true
                    }
                 },
                 messages: {
                        name: {
                           required:"Please enter your name",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid name"
                        },
                        name2: {
                           required:"Please enter your name",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid name"
                        },
                        "ic-passport": {
                           required:"Please enter your IC/Passport Number",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid IC/Passport Number"
                        },
                        phone: { 
                           required: "Please enter your phone number",
                           minlength: "Please enter your valid phone number",
                           maxlength: "Please enter your valid phone number"
                        },
                        city: { 
                           required: "Please enter your City/Town & State",
                           minlength: "Please enter your valid City/Town & State",
                        },
                        email:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your email",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        },
                        dob:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Date of Birth",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth",
                        },
                        sex:{ 
                           required: "Please select your Gender",
                        },
                        tpt:{ 
                           required: "Please select if you own Transport",
                        },
                        licence:{ 
                           required: "Please select if you own a Licence",
                        },
                        travel:{ 
                           required: "Please select if you are willing to Travel",
                        },
                        language:{ 
                           required: "Please select what Language you speak",
                        },
                        ethnicity:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Ethnicity",
                        },
                        religion:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Religion",
                        },
                        age:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Age",
                        },
                        "hair-colour":{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Hair Colour",
                        },
                        "hair-length":{ 
                           required: "Please select your Hair Length",
                        },
                        "eye-colour":{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Eye Colour",
                        },
                        height:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Height",
                        },
                        weight:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Weight",
                        },
                        image1: "Please Choose at least 1 Photo",
                        bio: "Please enter your Bio",
                        experience: "Please enter your Experience",
                        femail: { 
                           required: "Please enter your email",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        }
                 },
                 debug: true,
                 errorElement: "em",
                 errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
                 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
                 },
                 success: function(label) {
                    label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
                 }  
             });
             var flag= $('#mailForm').valid();
             if(!flag){
                 return false;
             }
        },
        success: function(msg) {
           alert(msg);
           //$("#mailForm").addClass("hide");
           //$("#message1").show();
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            $("#mailForm").addClass("hide");
            $("#message1").show();
            $('#status').html(xhr.responseText);    
        }
    }); 
    $('#close').click(function(){ 
      $('#message1').hide();
      $("#mailForm").removeClass("hide");
      $('input[type=text],input[type=email],textarea,input[type=tel],input[type=date],input[type=url],input[type=file]').val('');
      location.reload();
     });
})();       
</script>
```

and now I have this sccript:

```
<script>

var input = document.getElementById('surname');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Last Name, minimum 2 characters');
}

var input = document.getElementById('name');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your First Name');
}

var input = document.getElementById('nric');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your NRIC or Passport number');
}

var input = document.getElementById('phone');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Phone number using format shown');
}

var input = document.getElementById('whatsapp');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Whatsapp using format shown');
}

var input = document.getElementById('city');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your City/Town and State');
}

var input = document.getElementById('email');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid E-mail address as shown');
}

var input = document.getElementById('femail');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid E-mail address as shown');
}

var input = document.getElementById('dob');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your date of birth as shown');
}

var input = document.getElementById('sex');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please select your Gender');
}

var input = document.getElementById('tpt');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please select if you own Transport');
}

var input = document.getElementById('licence');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please select if you have a licence');
}

var input = document.getElementById('licence');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please select if you have a licence');
}

var input = document.getElementById('language');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your spoken lanuage/s');
}

var input = document.getElementById('race');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Ethnicity');
}

var input = document.getElementById('religion');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Religion');
}

var input = document.getElementById('age');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Age');
}

var input = document.getElementById('haircolour');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Haircolour');
}

var input = document.getElementById('hairlength');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please select your Hair Length');
}

var input = document.getElementById('eyes');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Eye Colour');
}

var input = document.getElementById('height');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Height');
}

var input = document.getElementById('weight');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Weight');
}

var input = document.getElementById('image1');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please choose a suitable photo, min 5 required');
}

var input = document.getElementById('image2');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please choose a suitable photo, min 5 required');
}

var input = document.getElementById('image3');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please choose a suitable photo, min 5 required');
}

var input = document.getElementById('image4');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please choose a suitable photo, min 5 required');
}

var input = document.getElementById('bio');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Bio');
}

var input = document.getElementById('experience');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please enter your detailed Experience');
}

</script>
```

But now I don't know how to make the form talk back to the mail.php and action it as it did before I changed it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading and offering a novice some assistance.

Comment: This isn't HTML5 Validation but jquery validation plugin.You need to use `submitHandler` , see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518895/jquery-validation-plugin-callback-for-field-success-validation) for details

Comment: The code I showed you was just to have custom messages against my error message, the html form code I didn't show, would have been pointless I thought. But I will have a look anyway thanks.

Comment: I just had a look... My form works exactly as I need it to, but now I need to send it off to my mail.php doc so it can handle the form from there and do all it's emailing, etc
That's the bit I don't know how to do.

Comment: In submitHandler use `$('#myform').ajaxSubmit();`

Comment: Problem resolved... thanks for your help @Novice :) I also removed the Custom Error messages as it was causing too much drama.